# Can I access the "enclosing" object for an inlined function call in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Idea: Make an inlined convenience function to synchronize a function call on the "inlining" object's intrinsic lock:

```
public inline fun <T> intrinsicSync(block: () -> T): T {
    return synchronized(intrinsicLockOfTheObjectUsingTheFunction) {
        block()
    }
}

fun someFunction(parameter: SomeClass) {
    intrinsicSync(sharedResource.operation(parameter))
}
```

Is this possible? If not, is there a different but equally convenient way? I concede that

```
fun someFunction(parameter: SomeClass) {
    synchronized(this) {
        sharedResource.operation(parameter)
    }
}
```

isn't the biggest hassle in the world, but I'd still like to know if it's possible to do something similar to what I imagined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most you can do is give the function a receiver (i.e. make it an extension function):

```
public inline fun <T> Any.intrinsicSync(crossinline block: () -> T): T {
                   // ^ within this function, `this` refers to the receiver
    return synchronized(this, block)
}
```

and then in a *member function*, you can do

```
this.intrinsicSync { sharedResource.operation() }
```

and since `this` is inferred you should be able to shorten this to

```
intrinsicSync { sharedResource.operation() }
```

---

Keep in mind that extension functions *cannot* shadow member functions, so if this object has another function with the same signature, it won't choose the extension function.

In your case, though, this seems unlikely.

Comment: Cool, cheers! Wasn't able to use it like this, but `intrinsicSync { sharedResource.operation() }` worked fine. Am I just doing it wrong or is this how it'll have to be? 100% Kotlin newbie

Comment: @EvenLislea ah, yes, `intrinsicSync(sharedResource.operation())` would pass the result of `operation` to the function. `{ sharedResource.operation() }` is a lambda expression/"function object" that returns the result once it is executed. I assumed `operation` returned a lambda, since this same syntax was used in your question - I'll edit my answer